# My server name is being cut off, Input: "Umod Server" Output: Umod

Tags: bash, ubuntu, echo

(https://prnt.sc/106y7u5)
Does anyone know how to solve it, it seems that there is something in entrypoint.sh that is deleting the ""

Here my entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/container

#Umod
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet/tools"
echo "PATH=\$PATH:\$HOME/.dotnet/tools; export PATH" >> ~/.profile

# fixes Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system
export DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=1
echo "DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=1; export DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT" >> ~/.profile

# Update Valheim Server
umod update core apps extensions --patch-available --strict --validate --prerelease

#Run Server
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}

# Replace Startup Variables
MODIFIED_STARTUP=`eval echo $(echo ${STARTUP} | sed -e 's/{{/${/g' -e 's/}}/}/g'))`
echo ":/home/container$ ${MODIFIED_STARTUP}"

# Run the Server
${MODIFIED_STARTUP}
```

And here my startup: [Env Var: STARTUP]

```
./valheim_server.x86_64 -nographics -batchmode -name "uMod CastBlack" -port 2481 -world "Dedicated" -password "umodgods" -public 1 valheim > >(sed -uE "[hidden]") & trap "[hidden]" 15; wait $!
```

Does anyone know how to solve it? I belive, the error is here:

```
# Replace Startup Variables
MODIFIED_STARTUP=`eval echo $(echo ${STARTUP} Y)`
echo ":/home/container$ ${MODIFIED_STARTUP}"

# Run the Server
${MODIFIED_STARTUP}
```

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your question. When you want to add `Y` to `STARTUP`, use `MODIFIED_STARTUP="${STARTUP} Y"`. Next three years you will not need `eval`.

Comment: Sorry, I spelled it wrong

Comment: I just changed it, I copied the wrong code when I went to ask the question

Comment: Are you trying to replace every `{{` into `${` in the string `./valheim_server.x86_64 -nographics -batchmode -name "uMod CastBlack" -port 2481 -world "Dedicated" -password "umodgods" -public 1 valheim > >(sed -uE "[hidden]") & trap "[hidden]" 15; wait $!`? There might be more problems, can you narrow down the part that is going wrong?